# How to combine 2 3D Rotations without canceling each other?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, catransform3d

I have a view which I want to rotate in two different directions.

The first is:

```
arrowImageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(rotationAngle, 0, 0, 1)
```

and the second is:

```
arrowImageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(pitch, 1, 0, 0)
```

**How can I combine these two rotations without canceling one out?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You combine 3D transformations with [`CATransform3DConcat()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreAnimation_functions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CATransform3DConcat):

```
let t1 = CATransform3DMakeRotation(rotationAngle, 0, 0, 1)
let t2 = CATransform3DMakeRotation(pitch, 1, 0, 0)
arrowImageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(t1, t2)
```

Comment: Animating `arrowImageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(t1, t2)` would obviously animate the transformations in sync. Is there a way to concatenate these transformations but animate them separately (so that each transformation has its own easing curve)?